# RF-kill Wi-Fi blocked

Tags: wifi, linux

Столкнулся с такой проблемой. После включения нетбука (asus) network manager перестал видеть точки доступа. Первым делом я заглянул в терминал и обнаружил, что wlan0 down, попробовал его поднять - без результата! Ифэйс появился, но, хоть убей, все равно в down.
Сначала попробовал #rfkill list all - блокирует! Ага) rfkill unblcok wifi - разблокировали!
Теперь поднимаем wlan0, и точек доступа по-прежнему не видим, фавля не цепляется. После долгого поиска и гугления нашел такой файлик /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
Открываем nano, видим следующее:

```
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

Включаем:

```
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true
```

Делаем reboot, вафля по прежнему не цепляется.

В терминале:

`# rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: yes`

Далее выполняем:

```
# rfkill unblock wifi
```

Внимание! Вот с этого момента поднимается wlan0 и сам цепляет родную точку доступа.
Естественно, проблема не решена, мы запускаем фавлю, но, как раньше, после запуска системы не цепляемся автоматически. Подскажите, в какую строну копать, писать скрипт для автозапуска - не выход, с проблемой подобного рода сталкиваюсь впервые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@r1za](/users/20886/r1za), на [форуме арча](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1273332) приводятся некоторые решения (а еще там пишут, что такие штуки начали происходить после обновления ядра, поэтому если такое произошло после обновления - я бы на вашем месте оформил багрепорт тому дистрибутиву, который вы используете).

Comment: проблема исчезла точно также как и появилась,я не вижу корней!пришел домой вкл нетбук,он загрузился,будто бы проблемы и не было,на данный момент тему считаю закрытой,все решение описано выше^ 

Etki: обновлений ядра не производилось,за то что откликнулся СПАСИБО!